# R: Obtaining the largest values for each column per id in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age Comorbidity_Comorbidity
1  1       male   90 1
1  2       male   91 2
1  3       male   92 3
2  1       female  87 1
2  2       female  88 2
2  3       female  89 3
3  1       male  50 1
3  2       male  51 2
3  3       male  52 3
4  1       female  54 1
4  2       female  55 2
4  3       female  56 3"
```

I would like to have for each `id` the maximum value that a variable takes (when numeric) and keep the string for the character variables (as this does not change). The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age Comorbidity_Comorbidity
1  3       male   92 3
2  3       female  89 3
3  3       male  52 3
4  3       female  56 3"
```

A possible solution could be done by using the function `group_by(id)` but I do not know how to proceed beyond that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by `id` column as well as all the character columns and take maximum of numeric columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, across(where(is.character))) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), max)) %>%
  ungroup

#     id sex     time   Age Comorbidity_Comorbidity
#  <int> <chr>  <int> <int>                   <int>
#1     1 male       3    92                       3
#2     2 female     3    89                       3
#3     3 male       3    52                       3
#4     4 female     3    56                       3
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), max, unique)(x)), id]
   id time    sex Age Comorbidity_Comorbidity
1:  1    3   male  92                       3
2:  2    3 female  89                       3
3:  3    3   male  52                       3
4:  4    3 female  56                       3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
nm1 <- c(names(df)[sapply(df, is.character)], "id")
aggregate(reformulate(nm1, response = "."), df, max)
     sex id time Age Comorbidity_Comorbidity
1   male  1    3  92                       3
2 female  2    3  89                       3
3   male  3    3  52                       3
4 female  4    3  56                       3
```